# Rewriting my vector shader to accommodate a slightly different fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have this vector shader (called "Vector Shader") that is all fine and dandy:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 values;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 rect;
layout (location = 2) in int depth;
layout (location = 3) in float radians;
layout (location = 4) in float effect;

layout (std140) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
};


out vec2 texCoord;

void main()
{
    vec2 transformed = vec2(values.xy * rect.zw*.5); //scale
    transformed = vec2(cos(radians)*transformed.x - sin(radians)*transformed.y,sin(radians)*transformed.x + cos(radians)*transformed.y); //rotate
    transformed += rect.xy + rect.zw*.5; //move
    gl_Position = projection*view*vec4(transformed,depth,1);
    texCoord = vec2(values.z,values.a);
}
```

This shader often passes data to this fragment shader (call it "Fragment Shader"):

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;
in vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D sprite;

void main()
{
    vec4 text = texture(sprite,texCoord);
    fragColor = text;
}
```

Together, my vertex and fragment shaders help me render sprites, cool!
Now I have another fragment shader (called "Paint Shader") that has one additional vec4 input, called "tint":

```
#version 330 core

//renders a sprite in a specific color

out vec4 fragColor;
in vec2 texCoord;
in vec4 tint;
uniform sampler2D sprite;

void main()
{
    vec4 text = texture(sprite,texCoord);
    if (text.w ==0)
    {
        fragColor = vec4(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fragColor = tint;
    }

}
```

I want to use Paint Shader with Vector Shader, but as far as I am aware (please correct if wrong), all my inputs into the fragment shader are either uniforms or outputs from the vertex shader. I may need to call Paint Shader a lot  using a lot of different values, which doesn't seem to match the idea of a uniform. But if I want to use the vertex shader, I have to create a whole new vertex shader that uses the same code as before with the only difference being that it now outputs the vec4 that Paint Shader will use, like so:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 values;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 rect;
layout (location = 2) in int depth;
layout (location = 3) in float radians;
layout (location = 4) in float effect;
layout (location = 5) in vec4 tint_;

layout (std140) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
};


out vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 tint;

void main()
{
    vec2 transformed = vec2(values.xy * rect.zw*.5); //scale
    transformed = vec2(cos(radians)*transformed.x - sin(radians)*transformed.y,sin(radians)*transformed.x + cos(radians)*transformed.y); //rotate
    transformed += rect.xy + rect.zw*.5; //move
    gl_Position = projection*view*vec4(transformed,depth,1);
    texCoord = vec2(values.z,values.a);
    tint = tint_;
}
```

Now I have two vertex shaders that do effectively the same thing but because of the fragment shader they differ by 3 lines. If I ever decide to change how my vertex shaders work, I now have to change both of them rather than just one.

Is there a way to do this without creating a 2nd vertex shader? Could I use this 2nd iteration of a vertex shader with the original fragment shader but just ignore the "tint" output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid rewriting code, use the preprocessor.

e.g. in you shader code use something like this

```
#ifdef THIS_CONSTANT
//some code
#elif THAT_CONSTANT
//some other code
#else
//alternative code, or #error "requirements are not met"
#endif
```

then, when you're creating your shader, you simply need to pass two (or more) source strings to `glShaderSource`

```
const char *constants = 
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "#define THIS_CONSTANT\n"
    "//or #define THAT_CONSTANT\n";

const char *vs_or_fs_src = "your main code";

//pass this to glShaderSource
const char *shader_src[] = {
    constants,
    vs_or_fs_src
};
```

A simple, effortless method is to use a bitmask and let your shader manager create a specific shader program on the fly (if not exists) based on the bits that are set in the mask.

And yes, you'll end up with multiple shader programs but with only one single source file (for each shader type).

Comment: Wow this is really cool! Kinda surprised that I've never heard of it before, now that I've seen it, every forum seems to mention it as a common way to make your shaders DRY. Really appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: @Ruglord Ever heard the term "uber shader"? The same principle is used here but in contrast to an "uber shader", here we're using the preprocessor compile time branching (`#if`) instead of runtime branching (`if`).

Comment: I have not! Do you have any good resources on it?

Comment: Sorry, no, i actually don't have any resources on that topic. Just "google" it. Simply put, an "uber shader" is a multipurpose shader with the downside, that it has to evaluate the state at runtime and branch the code (`if/else`). If you consider that a fragment shader is called for each fragment, a lot of branchibg will occur (which is considered bad). Nowadays, specialized shaders are used which contain only the necessary code. If we now consider that we have to implement a shader for each possible combination of different states, code duplication is unavoidable.

Comment: Therefore, if we combine the best of the two paradigms, you'll end up with what i've shown in my answer. So basically a "compile time uber shader" (instead of runtime).

Comment: As a hint, "uber shaders" are relicts from the ancient past, don't spent too much time on that topic.